# SGE DRMAA python job process

Tags: python, drmaa

I am using Python drmaa library to launch jobs on a SGE cluster. My services is available on REST API, during my test, all work fine, jobs are submitted / waited for completion / results retrieved once finished. Process is run once, in the same drmaa session.

On my web interface, the job is not processed : - job submission - job launched on SGE - job status on another time (via a call to drmaa.session.jobStatus(jobId)

Each time I run process to get job status, I get 'The job specified by the 'jobid' does not exist.'

I guess this is because I do not run "submission" and "status" request in the same drmaa session.

Is there a way to get a job status from another session ?

Thnxs.

Comment: It would be helpful if you include a concrete example of what you are trying to accomplish. Also, I had better results with [saga-python](https://github.com/radical-cybertools/saga-python) than with DRMAA. Here is a [quick tutorial](http://saga-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/index.html) you can try to see if it works for you.

Comment: Thanxs for your response, I'll give a try to saga-python :-). Giving a piece of code as example is not easy, as my source code rely on the galaxyproject drmaa library. Anyway, I am thinking the problem is more related to my SGE local configuration, as manually running qstat give me the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found why this is not working : Finished job cannot be accessed anymore with 'qstat' method on seg (I guess this is the underlying command executed when asking for a job status via drmaa library). Some work is in progress with drmaav2 for sge which seems to solve the problem ([efficient way to wait for job completion : python and drmaa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937081/efficient-way-to-wait-for-job-completion-python-and-drmaa))

Comment: You can use `qacct -j {job_id}` to get the status of finished jobs.